# Looping values from excel sheet in UFT

Tags: vba, excel, qtp

Please can anyone help me !!!!

I have this function that calls data from an external excel workbook and places the value into the application under test, I need it to loop through all the values in the excel sheet row by row

Below is the link to the framework and the function I am trying to use and need it to loop through the values in the excel sheet. PLS HELP.

MANY THANKS

http://www.automationrepository.com/2013/08/designing-hybrid-framework-in-qtp-part-3/

```
'================================================================================
'Function name - fnFetchDataFromExcelSheet
'Description - This function retrieves the data from the excel sheet based upon the column name
'================================================================================
Function fnFetchDataFromExcelSheet(strColumnName)

    Dim sColValue

    'Initialize the return the value to "empty" string
    fnFetchDataFromExcelSheet = "empty"

    'Add a new blank sheet into the QTP data table
    'Excel data will be copied into this blank sheet
    DataTable.AddSheet("dtDataSheet")

    'Import the data from the excel sheet into the QTP data table
    DataTable.ImportSheet sExcelWorkbookPath, sSheetName, "dtDataSheet"

    'Find the value from the data table
    sColValue = DataTable.Value(strColumnName, "dtDataSheet")

    'Return the value back to the calling function
    fnFetchDataFromExcelSheet = sColValue

    'Remove Reference
    DataTable.DeleteSheet("dtDataSheet")

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function you have posted from a site is not correct logically!

First, You need to pass both sSheetName & strColumnName to the function.

Even if we ignore that it is a miss by mistake Or Assume that sSheetName is a global variable (so need to pass this to function), For each and every call to this function, It  imports a sheet to the datatable, gets the value in the first row for the given cell and agains delete it(!!!). It would affect the performance very badly. You will also get the same value everytime!!

I would say, Ignore the function. Follow these steps.

1) First you need to import the excel into your datatable.

```
DataTable.ImportSheet /path/to/excel, /name/of/the/sheet, "dtDataSheet"
```

/path/to/excel & /name/of/the/sheet should be in "  "

2) get the Row count

```
intRowcount=DataTable.GetSheet("dtDataSheet").RowCount
```

3) Use a simple For loop

```
For iLoop = 1 To intRowcount

  DataTable.GetSheet("dtDataSheet").SetCurrentRow iLoop
  Msgbox DataTable.value("ColumnName","dtDataSheet")  'Replace the msgbox with what you want

Next
```